# Recorrer una consulta POO

Tags: php

Estoy creando mi propio **Framework** básico y solo me falta recorrer una consulta `SELECT` ya me quede pausado en la `function get_query` ya confirme que llega la consulta con su parametro `"SELECT * FROM status WHERE id_status=1"` pero al recorrer el **WHILE** es donde me marca el error lo quiero hacer con la función de `mysql mysqli_fetch_array`.

Una ayudita por favor.

```
//metodo privado para conectarse a bd
private function db_open(){
    $this->conn = new mysqli(self::$db_Host,self::$db_root,self::$db_pass,$this->db_name);
    $this->conn->set_charset(self::$db_charset);
}

private function db_close(){
    $this->conn->close();
}

//establecer un query simple que afecte datos de tipo insert , delete , update
protected function set_query(){
$this->db_open();
//metodo query heredado de mysqli
$this->conn->query($this->query);
$this->db_close();
}

//obtener resultados de una consulta tipo select en un array
protected function get_query(){
    $this->db_open();
    echo $this->query;
    $result = $this->conn->query($this->query);
    var_dump($result);
    while( $this->registro = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) );
    var_dump($this->registro);
    //cerrar consulta de result
    $result->close();
    //cerrams conexion con base de datos
    $this->db_close();
    //quita el ultimo elemento del arreglo arraypop
    return ($this->registro);
}
}
```

Comment: _pero al recorrer el WHILE es donde me marca el error_ **¿Qué error?**

Comment: el bucle `while` necesitaría de corchetes `{}`si quisieras utilizar el `var_dump` para cada uno de los registros que te devuelva.

Comment: no marca error solo que no muestra lo que estoy trayendo de $result esto es lo que me imprime   1 SELECT * FROM `status` WHERE id_status=1mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )

Comment: no todavia no queda    protected function get_query(){
  $this->db_open();
  $result = $this->conn->query($this->query);
  while( $this->rows = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){
  var_dump($this->rows);
  }
  //cerrar consulta de result
  $result->close();
  //cerrams conexion con base de datos
  $this->db_close();
  //quita el ultimo elemento del arreglo arraypop
  return ($this->rows);
 }

Comment: public function read($id_status = ''){
  $this->query = ($id_status != '')
  ? (" SELECT * FROM `status` WHERE id_status=$id_status") 
  : (" CALL seleccionar() ");
  $this->get_query();
  $data = array();
  foreach ($this->rows as $key => $value) {
   $data[$key] = $value;
  }
  var_dump($data);
  return $data;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo tú quieres construir un array con los resultados obtenidos.

Una forma de hacerlo sería esta:

```
protected function get_query(){
    $this->db_open();
    echo $this->query;
    $result = $this->conn->query($this->query);

    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    /*Esto es una prueba de impresión en pantalla*/
    /*Lo puedes quitar luego*/
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        echo $row['id_status'];
        echo $row['status'];
    }

    //cerrar consulta de result
    $result->close();
    //cerrams conexion con base de datos
    $this->db_close();

    /*Aquí va el array creado dentro del while 
     *Si quieres aplicar arraypop sobre $rows 
     *también puedes hacerlo antes del return
    */

    return $rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas no estás realizando nada en el bucle ya que no estás englobando nada dentro de los corchetes del mismo. De hecho, lo finalizas con un `;` por lo que tu `while` ahora mismo no está haciendo nada. Simplemente recorriendo las filas.

```
while( $this->registro = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) );
var_dump($this->registro); //Esta fuera del bucle
```

Deberías englobarlo dentro de los corchetes `{}` para poder ver los resultados:

```
while($this->registro = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    var_dump($this->registro);
}
```

Comment: ya lo cambie como ustedes dicen pero me marca error al recorrer el array   array(2) { ["id_status"]=> string(1) "1" ["status"]=> string(11) "coming soon" } 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc_adminlte\model\prueba.php on line 27
array(0) { }